# Conditional VLOOKUP based on dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have two tables I want to merge in Excel:

| Date | Email |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-07-07 06:49:10 | mail1 |
| 2019-07-14 20:21:16 | mail2 |
| 2019-06-23 18:22:40 | mail3 |
| 2019-08-11 13:17:54 | mail4 |

And

| Date | Email | Article number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02/04/2019 15:11 | mail1 | No 1 |
| 08/08/2019 20:21 | mail1 | No 5 |
| 05/06/2019 16:30 | mail2 | No 1 |
| 07/09/2019 13:00 | mail2 | No 2 |
| 08/09/2019 12:43 | mail2 | No 3 |
| 05/05/2019 18:13 | mail3 | No 7 |
| 28/06/2019 09:00 | mail4 | No 6 |

I want to merge these tables on Email. For 'mail3' and 'mail4', this should be pretty straightforward, they get No 7 and No 6. However, for 'mail1' and 'mail2', this is more difficult. I want to merge them comparing the dates, so that they get the Article number related to the date closest to but **before** the date in table 1. I tried regular VLOOKUP to merge on email, but can't really figure out if it's possible to do this conditionally. Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please [Edit] your post and add the expected output will help us to match with our results,, since I've applied two different formula getting 2 different sequence!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should opt for `INDEX` and `MATCH` along with `AGGREGATE`. This combo is always at least as fast as `VLOOKUP` and at best a LOT faster!

So here is an example:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=INDEX($G$2:$G$8,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,3,($F$2:$F$8=B2)*($E$2:$E$8<A2)*($E$2:$E$8),1),$E$2:$E$8,0))
```

Drag down...

---

To answer @Rajesh his concerns below, this works on any row as long as you update the references accordingly, row 1, 100, 1000, 100000. It doens't matter. Don't forget to use true date values and `TRIM` the sample data given by OP:

[image]

Formula in `C182`:

```
=INDEX($G$182:$G$188,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,3,($F$182:$F$188=B182)*($E$182:$E$188<A182)*($E$182:$E$188),1),$E$182:$E$188,0))
```

Comment: Just check it doesn't works properly when cell reference changes!!

Comment: @RajeshS, what part would not work in this example if I may ask?

Comment: ,, returns No 1, #NA, No 7 then rest are #NA,, i'm using entire set in Range `A181:F188` including Header & Formula in `C182`.

Comment: @RajeshS, the formula works fine. You might not have used the right references. It doesn't matter if I put this data in row 1 or row 1000 or 100000, as long as you change the references accordingly it will work.

Comment: ,, no my cell reference are true and correct,, once you try at different location like I did!!

Comment: @RajeshS, can you show me through chat? I tried and it works just as intended. Did you clean the data from OP > through `TRIM`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97550/discussion-between-jvdv-and-rajesh-s).

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

*This simple array (CSE) formula finds the closest match for the date & fixes the issue:*

[image]

**Edited Formula in Q2:**

```
{=IF(ISBLANK(O2),"",IFERROR(INDEX($U$2:$U$9,MATCH(1,(P2=$T$2:$T$9)*(O2>=S$2:S$9),1)),""))}
```

- Finish the formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill it down.

**N.B.**

- Closet match is discretionary issue, it may be `Greater/Less than or Equals to the Criteria Date.`
- So, accordingly the comparison operator may be altered in this part of the formula with `(O2>=S$2:S$9)`.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: This does not work, simply because if there is more data, for example `04/06/19` for mail2 in columns `S:T` you will get the first, and wrong, match.

Comment: @JvdV, my data has Date MM/DD/YY HH:MM,,

Comment: add another row of data to `S:U` with for example `04/06/19` (just any date before 05/06/19) for mail2 and No 0. You'll see what I mean. It will pull No 0 where No 1 is expected.

Comment: I've replaced `05/06/19 16:30 mail2 No 1` in `Row 4` with `04/06/19 16:30 mail2 No 1` get the correct sequence and if is replaced with `04/06/19 16:30 mail2 No 0` then sequence is `1,0,7,6` nothing wrong!!

Comment: Don't replace the data, add another row of data. Like this [example](https://imgshare.io/image/knipsel.ZQue6)

Comment: @JvdV, I've added new Row at last `Row S9` this one `04/06/19 6:30 mail2 No 0` and in `Q2:Q5` I'm getting correct sequence `1,1,7,6`,, did you know Y coz,, the Date `04/06/19` is  smaller than Date `07/14/19 20:21 mail2` in Row `O3`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97580/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-jvdv).